# Parallel insert from R to MongoDB

Tags: r, mongodb, parallel-processing

**Question**

I am using the package [mongolite](https://github.com/jeroenooms/mongolite) to connect from R to MongoDB database. I want to see whether it is possible to do multiple insert in parallel into the database? While `mcmapply` in the parallel package works in other cases, it doesn't seem to work for multiple insertion into MongoDB.

**Example codes**

I have a data frame `grid.df` containing grid IDs and geographical locations for the grid points. I want to insert the `id_grid`, `lon` and `lat` columns to the database.

```
    insert.grid <- function(i){

           # check which data to insert            
            criteria <- sprintf('{"id_grid" : %s}', id_grid[i])

           # values to be inserted
            newdoc <- sprintf('{"$set" : {"id_grid" : %s, "loc" : {"type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [%s, %s] } }   }', 
                              grid.df$id_grid[i], 
                              round(grid.df$lon[i], digits = 4),
                              round(grid.df$lat[i], digits = 4)
            )
            inserted <- F
            while (!inserted) {
              inserted <- gcon$update(query = criteria, update = newdoc, upsert = T)
            }
          }
```

**Attempts**

**1) Using mcmapply**

mcmapply works fine with 1 core. However, as soon as I try to use multiple cores, it fails.

```
results <- mcmapply(insert.grid, 1:nrow(grid.df), mc.cores = 4)
```

Setting `mc.preschedule` parameter to FALSE didn't help neither.

```
results <- mcmapply(insert.grid, 1:nrow(grid.df), mc.cores = 4, mc.preschedule = FALSE)
```

Both are giving the following error:

> Warning message: In mclapply(seq_len(n), do_one, mc.preschedule =
>   mc.preschedule,  :   all scheduled cores encountered errors in user
>   code

**2) Using file locks**

I also followed the approach introduced here: http://www.quintuitive.com/2014/11/20/synchronization-for-r-with-the-flock-package/ and while it works with multiple cores, I do not really gain much in the performance since making the locks for every insert completely slows down the process and it similar to use 1 core.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was solved by moving the `gcon` connection inside the function definition. The problem was simply that only one connection was defined and could not work for parallel insert.